# Pull a git repository using web php script

Tags: github

I need to pull a github repository on my cloud server using a script from web. I created a php script to access a shell script file. 
There are 4 commands that I use when I do a pull:

```
sudo su
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add
git pull repository master
```

The problem is when the script does the `ssh-add` I have to type a password, how can I type a password in a shell script?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [keychain](http://www.funtoo.org/wiki/Keychain) instead of `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` -- `keychain` will start an `ssh-agent` if necessary, or use the existing `ssh-agent`. So with `keychain`, you only type in your passphrase at the start of your session when `keychain` is starting an `ssh-agent`.

I use `keychain` from my .bash_profile like:

```
eval `keychain --eval id_rsa`
```